# Display a button based on a login comparison

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to implement a button.visible true/false based on the contents of a txt file. Everything I've written to date is unstable at best. This is for a Winform stand alone application in the main dialog box.

In an ideal world it seems it should be simpler. I want the code to open `Permissions.txt`, which I know I am successfully accessing as the `MessageBox` will show the first name in the list, and compare the `Environment.UserName` with all of the names in the `.txt` file. Once the button is displayed it opens a new dialog box.

Anyone willing to teach a newcomer. I've been searching for a while and I don't see it.

I have also tried working with `File.Readlines` with no success.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you're willing to provide.

Frank Pytel

```
public void hideWidget()
    {
        //gets the users login name from the system
        string newName = userNameOnly();

        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
           new System.IO.StreamReader(dataFolder + "\\Permissions.txt");


        //This next bit called Original Code works on my local when I access it, when accessed from a server, but not for other users.
        //Original code
        //while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        //{
        //    if (line == newName)
        //    {
        //        WidgetForm.Visible = true;
        //    }
        //    else
        //    {
        //        WidgetForm.Visible = false;
        //    }
        //    //MessageBox.Show(line);
        //    counter++;
        //}

        //file.Close();               


//This is where I am at currently. Again it's not picking up all of the names in the .txt file.

        while (file.ReadLine() != null)
        {

            //string line;
            string line = file.ReadLine();

            if (newName == file.ReadLine())
            {
                WidgetForm.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                WidgetForm.Visible = true;
            }
            int counter = 0;

            //MessageBox.Show(line);
            //MessageBox.Show(file.ReadLine());
            counter ++;
        }

        //file.Close();

    }
```

EDITED....

Also if there is anyone that could possibly explain how string line; is being set to my user name. That is how it should have been set, but I've never told it line == newName in the original code. I thought that is what the `While` is for. To check to see if they are equal..

FINAL EDIT.

Here is what I got to work. Thanks @Bedford.

This portion goes directly below the Form1 class

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(dataFolder + "\\Permissions.txt");
```

This is the logic behind the hideWidget() button

```
        public void hideWidget()
    {
        //Make all userNames available to the logic
        string newName = userNameOnly();

        //variable to decide if userExists is true/false
        bool userExists;

        //Loop through all of the userNames in the file and see if it matches the userName login
        while (lines != null)
        {
            //Decide to make the button available if userExists does exist in the file
            if (lines != null)
            {
                userExists = lines.Any(ln => ln == newName);

                WidgetForm.Visible = userExists;
            }

                //Do nothing if the userName does not match anyone in the Permissions.txt file. The button default Visible is false
            else
            {

            }
            return;
        }
    }
```

I'm posting this snippet so that others might benefit from it. Thanks again @Bedford. This NEWB really appreciates the assistance. HAGD!! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read all the lines from a file with the File.ReadAllLines static method, and then use a LINQ query to check whether any of the lines match the user name:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(dataFolder, "Permissions.txt"));
bool userExists = lines.Any(ln => ln == newName); // or any comparison you like

// use the bool variable to set the visibility
WidgetForm.Visible = userExists;
```

Comment: Should always use `Path.Combine`. Internally it will figure out if the arguments start/end with backslashes and combine them properly.

Comment: @muffin Man  I did                      '
        internal static string appPath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
        internal static string dataFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, "Data");
        internal static string reportFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, "Report");
        internal static string weeklyFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, "Weekly");
'

Comment: I am new to this. I hope I did those internal's correctly to do the combine??

Comment: @FrankPytel, I don't think you need the `internal` modifiers for those variables. Muffin Man was just talking about how `Path.Combine` method works.

Comment: @PredragDjukic Copy. I was hoping to use them later in the code.

Comment: @Bedford Thank You. I had to play with it some but your solution worked perfectly. :)